# some powershell commands work from C# ... others won't

Tags: c#, powershell, appcmd

I created a powershell script:

```
mkdir C:\kevin\mySite.com
mkdir C:\kevin\mySite.com\stylesheets
mkdir C:\kevin\mySite.com\slideshows
mkdir C:\kevin\mySite.com\images
mkdir C:\kevin\mySite.com\file
mkdir C:\kevin\mySite.com\js

c:/windows/system32/inetsrv/appcmd add site /name:"mySite.com" /id:187          /physicalPath:C:\kevin\mySite.com
```

If I run this in powershell it works fine.
I tried running it from a c# web page (code below) the mkdir commands works but the appcmd does not

```
private string ExecuteScript(string psScript)
{
    string status="";
    try
    {
        Runspace rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        rs.Open();
        using (rs)
        {
            Pipeline pp = rs.CreatePipeline(psScript);
            pp.InvokeAsync();
        }
        rs.Close();
    }
    catch (InvalidRunspaceStateException ex)
    {
        status = ex.ToString();
    }
    return status;
}
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Your c# app probably doesn't have rights to the c:\windows\system32\inetsrv folder.  Are you running as administrator?

Comment: please show the error you receive

Comment: On a VPS and getting above my level of knowledge here.  The web application is a member of IIS_IUSRS.  This group does not have any rights on c:\..\inetsrv and it doesn't look like I can change that.

Comment: The code is not quite correct. Use `pp.Invoke()` instead of `pp.InvokeAsync()`. It looks like you close the pipeline before it finishes its work in the background (async).

Comment: I had originally used pp.Invoke(), just tried it again, same result.

Comment: Roman, how should I close it?

Comment: Leon, I don't get an error - or I'm not sure how to get the error.  The try does not catch anything

Comment: Use `pp.Invoke()` and close how you close now. With `pp.InvokeAsync()` you should wait for the pipeline to complete and only then close it. If you are interested in details then ask another, specific question about this.

Comment: "I had originally used pp.Invoke(), just tried it again, same result" -- So the problem is not only in use of `pp.InvokeAsync()` and premature `Close()`. But the code is still not quite correct, FYI.

Comment: NB: `rs.Close()` seems to be redundant together with `using(rs)`.